# Geometrical proof

Tags: geometry

In the triangle $\Delta$XYZ the two sides XY and XZ are equal (XY=XZ). The circle is circumscribed to the triangle which means that all three corners of the triangle tangent the circle. The radius of the circle is 1 and its center is the point C.

I know that the radius CY is a bisection to the angle Y.

I want to prove that the distance of the side YZ is equal to $\sqrt{3}$, note that i want to prove that these two facts are equivalent (a=b means that b=a) so i can only use claim A (CY is a bisection to the angle Y) and the given facts in the first paragraph when proving that YZ is equal to $\sqrt{3}$.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Qchh.jpg)

What I've done is the following:

Since the sides XY and XZ is equal the triangle should be an isosceles triangle, this would mean that the angle Z is equal to the angle Y. If I where to drag a line from the center C to the corner Z this line CZ would be a bisection equal to CY. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl222AH.jpg)

This is where I get stuck, I'm thinking that dragging a line from the center C to the corner A (CA) and proving that the triangle is equilateral would allow me to calculate XZ but I don't know how to prove this.

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Note that $\Delta CYX$ is isosceles, and since $CY$ is also an angle bisector of $\angle Y$, we get $\hat X=\hat Y$.

Answer (score 1):

We can see that both $\triangle{XCY}$ and $\triangle{XCZ}$ are isosceles. Thus $\angle{CXZ} \cong \angle{CZX}$ and $\angle{CXY} \cong \angle{CYX}$. But we also know that $\angle{XYZ} \cong \angle{XZY}$ which means all angles are equal in $\triangle{XYZ}$. Now to find the side of the $\triangle{XYZ}$ we apply the law of sines: $\frac{XY}{\sin 60°}=2$ (diameter of circumcircle). $2XY=2\sqrt{3}$, $XY=\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 0):

You must know that the center $C$ is the intersection of the perpendicular bissectors and since $CY$ is an angle bissector your triangle is equilateral.  Now the altitude from $ X$ is $1.5$
then you apply Pythagorus in  $CZY$ to get $YZ$.

Everthing is reversible here.